# Messing with 'when not matched' in SQL (how to merge properly)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, merge

I'm creating several tables and merging data from them into one. These tables have similar columns col1 and col2 but the values in these columns can be different, ex. col1 on row 1 from tab1 may have "0" and col1 from tab2 may have  on the same row in col1 "1". ONLY in this case I need to update the value from tab1 in col1 on the row 1. Take a look at the following example:

```
BEFORE MERGING               
tab1:
id col1 col2
1  0    0
2  0    1
3  0    0
                              AFTER MERGING WITH tab2
tab2:                         tab1:
id col1 col2                   id col1 col2
1  1    0           --->       1  1    0
2  0    0                      2  0    1
3  0    0                      3  0    0
```

For that purpose I use the following query:

```
merge into tab1 st
   using (select id, col1, col2 from tab2) ss
   ON (st.id=ss.id)
    when matched then 
    update set  st.col1 = ss.col1,
                st.col2 = ss.col2 

  where ss.col1 != 0 or ss.col2 != 0
  when not matched then
    insert (st.id, st.col1, st.col2)
    values (ss.id, ss.col1, ss.col2)
    ;
```

I'm just learning sql so only now I noticed that this query is not correct. It can overwrite the "1" value in the tab1 with "0" coming from tab2. Help me to improve this query please, I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Didn't think MySQL supported Merge...

Comment: this is a simplified version, in reality I create 4 tables and try to merge them with the first one, updating only the cells that != 0. I wonder if a condition like "when col1 not matched col2 then insert col2 value col2" could be implemented here...

Comment: I use oracle, sorry for mislead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression when setting the values to control which value gets assigned.  Try something like:

```
merge into tab1 st
   using (select id, col1, col2 from tab2) ss
   ON (st.id=ss.id)
    when matched then 
    update set  st.col1 = CASE WHEN st.col1 = 0 THEN ss.col1 ELSE st.col1 END,
                st.col2 = CASE WHEN st.col2 = 0 THEN ss.col2 ELSE st.col2 END

  where ss.col1 != 0 or ss.col2 != 0
  when not matched then
    insert (st.id, st.col1, st.col2)
    values (ss.id, ss.col1, ss.col2)
    ;
```

Thus in the WHEN MATCHED situation, if the value from tab1 (st) is zero you change it to the value from tab2 (ss), otherwise you just set the value from tabl1 to itself.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You should update with the max of `{ss.coln, st.coln}`. For example, using [`GREATEST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions069.htm#SQLRF00645):

```
MERGE INTO tab1 st
USING (SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM tab2) ss
ON (st.id = ss.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET st.col1 = greatest(ss.col1, st.col1), 
          st.col2 = greatest(ss.col2, st.col2)
    WHERE ss.col1 > st.col1
       OR ss.col2 > st.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (st.id, st.col1, st.col2) 
   VALUES (ss.id, ss.col1, ss.col2);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I shall use your solution, it's a bit shorter;)